# php mysql select WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, video

**hi** 
I want to fetch from the database in the following way

```
SELECT title FROM video WHERE REPLACE(title, '-', title) < title='video 03' ;
```

So I want to replace '-' Or any other symbols And then select the result if they are smaller Of exp : 'video 03'

Now, for example, I have

'video-01 , video_02 ... '

Note: random storage, and the name is not stable, sometimes 10 characters and sometimes 15 characters ...Therefore impossible to use SUBSTRING

Now I'm having trouble, some title contains Arabic characters, how can I replace all characters and just keep number

Comment: You should probably be using an "id" to identify the video just by a number, which would be much easier and more efficient than how you're trying to do it, it seems.

Comment: You are a Killer! (*of an `INDEX`, by the way `:D`*) why are you not using primary keys?

Comment: Why exactly is your question? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Try to use SUBSTRING statement for extracting last two or three digit and then compare with some sample.

Comment: Note: random storage, and the name is not stable, sometimes 10 characters and sometimes 15 characters ...Therefore impossible to use SUBSTRING

Comment: Can you clarify your question by giving some example rows you do want to select, and some you don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you could use REPLACE function this way:

```
SELECT title
FROM video
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(title, '-', ' '), '_', ' ') < 'video 03';
```

This will return 'video 01', 'video-02', 'video_02', etc.

**Edit:** You could also use this, that separates the alphanumeric part of the title from the numeric part:

```
select
  title,
  first_digit,
  left(title, first_digit-1) as alphanumeric_part,
  mid(title, first_digit, length(title)-first_digit+1) as digits
from (
  select
    least(case when locate('0', title)>0 then locate('0', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('1', title)>0 then locate('1', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('2', title)>0 then locate('2', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('3', title)>0 then locate('3', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('4', title)>0 then locate('4', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('5', title)>0 then locate('5', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('6', title)>0 then locate('6', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('7', title)>0 then locate('7', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('8', title)>0 then locate('8', title) else length(title)+1 end,
          case when locate('9', title)>0 then locate('9', title) else length(title)+1 end) first_digit,
    title
  from
    video
) video_pos
where mid(title, first_digit, length(title)-first_digit+1)+0 < 2
```

see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/477a3/1).

Comment: Now I'm having trouble, some title contains Arabic characters, how can I replace all characters and just keep number

Comment: @user2039770 pls have a look at my updated answer, but I think it's better to normalize your data, and have two different columns one for the title, one for the numeric part

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do many request:

```
//string that needs to be customized
$title = "video 03";
$title = str_replace("-", " ", $title);

$title_array=explode(' ', $title);
$number=$title_array[1];

echo $number;
echo $title;
```

Do your SQL here by retrieving all video under the video number